# Object Oriented Graphics And Painters

Tags: oop, graphics

When creating an object that will be graphically represented but also have data and functionality independent of that representation (i.e., a card in a card game will have a graphic, but also know its value, suit, maybe be able to flip over), from a best practices approach, should that object know its own image and position?
If not, how should it be handled? I understand that at the very least another class should be responsible for drawing said object, and it appeals to me that the class shouldn't need to be concerned with its graphics at all: the program should be able to change the design and look of the cards without impacting the class itself - a seven of spades is a seven of spades no matter how you draw it - but I'm finding it difficult to think up a solution to having the 'drawer' class know the image and location of the card.
My present solution is to have a sprite class, and the card contains a sprite object, which is constructed along with the card - the sprite simply contains an image and vector (location), but I feel that I could break this down.
Any design patterns or common sense solutions I'm missing? Or am I just thinking incorrectly that this should be separated?

Comment: I would submit that this is less an OOP question and more one of separation of concerns -- which, in a game setting, is up for debate depending on who you're talking to (and possibly beholden to the engine you're using as well)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a matter of opinion: I believe it would be best for the object not to know its own image.  It should know its own position.  When a card is drawn, like you mentioned, a Seven of Spades is a Seven of Spades.  Leave it to a different handler to draw the image based on what type of card it is, rather than asking the card for its image.

When you draw a card, you could make a method call, ex: drawCardImage(cardObject.type). The method could then check, using if statements, "if card == 'sevenofspades': draw("/images/sevenspades.png")